# attr_accessible is missing from the method list Module.instance_methods.grep /^attr/

Tags: ruby

I am looking for the `attr_*()`-like methods in `Module`. This code:

```
[BasicObject, Kernel, Object, Class, Module]
.each{|x|puts x.instance_methods.grep /^attr/}
```

only enlists:

```
attr_internal_reader
attr_internal_writer
attr_internal_accessor
attr_internal
```

Any ideas how to retrieve the `attr_reader` methods?

Comment: Isn't attr_reader in ActiveRecord::Base?

Comment: According to the ruby docs is here:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Module.private_instance_methods.grep(/\Aattr/)
# => [:attr, :attr_reader, :attr_writer, :attr_accessor]
```

Comment: I think it is inherited from Object, Module.private_methods(false) => [:inherited, :initialize]

Comment: @bjhaid Your guess is wrong, but the comment was suggestive. It is reflected in my edit. Try `Module.private_instance_methods(false)`.